# CodeIgniter Check if image existing with Jquery Ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, return

I would like check the image whether existing on server file system and the file list was store into database. I want to make a ajax call to doing validation then return the result to screen with append effect. Here is my code, but don't work :( Please help me.

**UPDATE:** Code is workable, but it's not my expectation, because three thousand record with caused timeout and No append effect. thanks

**Controller**

```
public function getImageList()
{
    $this->load->model('image_model');
    $data['list'] = $this->image_model->get_image();

    foreach ($data['list'] as $key){
        $result[] = $this->imageValidation($key->filename);
    }
        header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
        echo(json_encode($result));
}

private function imageValidation($imgfile)
{
    if(!file_exists(LOCAL_IMG_TEMP.$imgfile))
    {
        return "<pre>". $imgfile." Not Find"."</pre>";
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script>

function makeAjaxCall(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.php/ajax/getImageList",
        cache: false,
        dataType : "json", 
        success: function(data){
            $("p").append(data);
        }
 });
}
</script>
</script>


<input type='button' id='PostBtn' value='Check Image' onclick='javascript:makeAjaxCall();' />

<p></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of what the json feed looks like coming from: http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.php/ajax/getImageList

Comment: Yes, it is direct download from getImageList() method
IMG:
http://postimg.org/image/fcmby1kav/

Answer (score 0):

try to use file_exists()
[check it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

Comment: Hi kamaljit,
Nothing happened when click the button :(

Comment: did you define route for getImageList?